# I want to copy a document from my tfs project to my local storage using c#

Tags: c#, tfs

I have some documents in my TFS project,I want to create a console application that reads the documents from TFS and copy the file to my local storage, any idea?

Comment: Yeah, there is an idea. Do: Use the TFS API to fetch the file and System.IO classes to write it to disc. Don't: Use StackOverflow as your code writing service. Try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code in [this article](https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/team-foundation-server-api-programmatically-downloading-files-from-source-control/), which works for you:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "http://YourTfsUrl:8080/tfs/YourTeamProjectCollection";
            string filePath = @"C:\project\myfile.cs";

            // Get the version control server
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
            VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            // Get the latest Item for filePath
            Item item = versionControlServer.GetItem(filePath, VersionSpec.Latest);

            // Download and display content to console
            string fileString = string.Empty;

            using (Stream stream = item.DownloadFile())
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                    // Use StreamReader to read MemoryStream created from byte array
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray())))
                    {
                        fileString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(fileString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, you can also use [tf get command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) to get or download a specified version of one or more files or folders from TFS to the workspace, which is an easy way.

Comment: Have you tried the code snippet above? Is it working for you?